# Receive null values with SwiftyJSONModel in Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

After successful webservice call I get following json

```
"balance_details":{  
         "raw_balance":"13157.70",
         "raw_credit_adeded":"4035000.00",
         "raw_credit_deducted":"0.00",
         "raw_tot_paid_amount":6000,
         "tot_paid_amount":"Rs.6000.00",
         "tot_paid_invoices":2,
         "balance":"13157.7",
         "current_balance":"Rs.13157.70",
         "credit_added":"Rs.4035000.00",
         "credit_deducted":"Rs.0.00",
         "last_recharge_amt":null,
         "raw_amount":null,
         "last_recharge_date":""
      }
```

For this web call I'm using Alamofire. To map this JSON into SWIFT OBJECT, I'm using SwiftyJSONModel library. But I'm not able to set type for stoaring null values into JSON object.

```
class BalanceDetails: JSONObjectInitializable {

    // FIXME: - properties
    var rawBalance: String
    var rawCreditAdeded: String
    var rawCreditDeducted: String
    var rawTotalPaidAmount: Int
    var totalPaidAmount: String
    var totalPaidInvoices: Int
    var balance: String
    var currentBalance: String
    var creditAdded: String
    var creditDeducted: String
    //    var lastRechargeAmount: NSObject
    //    var rawAmount: NSObject
    var lastRechargeDate: String

    // FIXME: - json properties
    enum PropertyKey: String {
        case raw_balance
        case raw_credit_adeded
        case raw_credit_deducted
        case raw_tot_paid_amount
        case tot_paid_amount
        case tot_paid_invoices
        case balance
        case current_balance
        case credit_added
        case credit_deducted
        //        case last_recharge_amt
        //        case raw_amount
        case last_recharge_date
    }

    // FIXME: - initializer
    required init(object: JSONObject<PropertyKey>) throws {
        rawBalance = try object.value(for: .raw_credit_adeded)
        rawCreditAdeded = try object.value(for: .raw_credit_adeded)
        rawCreditDeducted = try object.value(for: .raw_credit_deducted)
        rawTotalPaidAmount = try object.value(for: .raw_tot_paid_amount)
        totalPaidAmount = try object.value(for: .tot_paid_amount)
        totalPaidInvoices = try object.value(for: .tot_paid_invoices)
        balance = try object.value(for: .balance)
        currentBalance = try object.value(for: .current_balance)
        creditAdded = try object.value(for: .credit_added)
        creditDeducted = try object.value(for: .credit_deducted)
        //        lastRechargeAmount = try object.value(for: .last_recharge_amt)
        //        rawAmount = try object.value(for: .raw_amount)
        lastRechargeDate = try object.value(for: .last_recharge_date)
    }
}
```

When I uncomment the commented lines from above code, xcode giving me error telling that "No 'value' candidates produce the expected contextual result type 'NSObject'". So my question is how I can set type for that JSON value so that it gets stored with class field.

Comment: decide if you are writing in objective c or swift? so you dont know what type you get? set it to Any

Comment: and first values are doubles or something not strings probably

Comment: For 'Any' following error appears; "Type '[BalanceDetails.PropertyKey]' has no member 'raw_amount'"

Comment: First values are strings. In response, values are with ""

Comment: so uncomment it

Comment: `null` represents `NSNull`. Does your object mapper consider that *key-exist-but-has-no-value* case? Personally I don't understand the practical benefit of those object mappers. It's not less code.

Comment: @vardian - I think you are right. I have to write my own custom JSON mapper with functionality to consider that key-exist-but-has-no-value case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot comment so I answer you here:

Think that maybe it is because the value of those keys are null, so I will try this:

```
     lastRechargeAmount = try? object.value(for: .last_recharge_amt) as? String
     rawAmount = try? object.value(for: .raw_amount) as? String
```

Comment: will try and let you inform.

Comment: could you show how can I declare, "var lastRechargeAmount: NSObject" and "var rawAmount: NSObject" for this to work?

Comment: I think doing it optional:

`var lastRechargeAmount: String?
 var rawAmount: String?`

Comment: yes your answer is working. I just used {lastRechargeAmount = try? object.value(for: .last_recharge_amt)
     rawAmount = try? object.value(for: .raw_amount) }. Typecasting at last is not necessary.